# realtime filling inputs after clon

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JS but got stuck on this. http://jsfiddle.net/h7vgxewL/ What I want to achieve is be able to change values in the clonned input. The problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("control-II-Art-list-line1").onkeyup = function() {
        document.getElementById("display-II-Art-list-line1").innerHTML = this.value;   
        }
```

If I add more fields I need to get this replicated for new line, like the line and input field, with the id:

```
control-II-Art-list-line2
```

Is there even way how to do it? Please check the fiddle and I think you will get what i mean. Thanks in advice.

Comment: This is not difficult to do. Do you want the inputs to be shown one under each other?

Comment: No I wanted to fill clonned fields in reatime like here http://jsfiddle.net/dd0w7skz/ Thank you for afford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery and event delegation it would be trivial. Delegated event listeners works for elements added in the future:

```
$('form').on('keyup', 'input', function(){
    $('#' + this.id.replace("control-", "display-")).html( this.value );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7vgxewL/3/

Or, in vanilla JS:

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
   var targetid, targetElement;
   if(e.target.id){
        targetid = e.target.id.replace("control-", "display-");
        targetElement = document.getElementById( targetid );
        if( targetElement ){
            targetElement.innerHTML = e.target.value;
        } 
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dd0w7skz/

Comment: Thanks kindly sir ... I owe you a beer ;)